# Cannot add Tweet Composer dependency

Tags: android, android-sharing, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to add new TweetComposer to my project at module "app":

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.5@aar') {
           transitive = true;
    }
}
```

And I always got error like this:

> Error:Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.5.
>   Required by:
>       reader-android:app:unspecified
>   Search in build.gradle files

Comment: try this tutorial... https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/twitter-login-android-tutorial-integrating-twitter-login/

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue:
add at project level the following code

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
```

And at application level

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

You should then be able to sync Gradle correctly, let me know if that works for you!

[Reference here](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android)